# two session overwriting in subdirectories

Tags: php, session

I have a website and a CMS panel located in sub-directory in the website. In the CMS panel I have session variables in which I write the username, level access etc.
The problem is that in the website I need to have user registration and login. When I try to log in the website, the two sessions are ovewritting each other and the end result is that the website session doesn't change(the user can't log in) and the CMS session receives the variables from the website session.

I searched the problem and saw someone suggesting that the two session should be named and therefore separated. I have session name on the website's session, but when I tried to name the second one I got server error.
The other thing that I saw was that the website's session is new with every page refresh, and this doesn't happen in the other one.
I don't have `session_destroy` or `session_unset`(regarding the session refresh problem).

What can be the problem and how to fix it?

EDIT
Maybe "ovewritting" is not the correct word. When I try to log in from the website nothing happens. When I try to log in the CMS I have the CMS session array AND the website's session array. I want them to be separated.

Comment: A quick workaround is to add a prefix to your sessions variables. For example a on the website you could store the value in $_SESSION["frontendsite_Username"]

Comment: But would that separeate the sessions? And in fact none of the session variables have the same name.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.. if a session get destryed in the one site it will get destryed in the other as well

Comment: I removed the name from the first session and the problem with session refresh is gone. Bur that doesn't solve the main issue. The two sessions are still interacting.